# Send Dictionary to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, core-data

I have a dictionary of key-value pairs that I am trying to save to core data.

```
let children = userSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let thisUser = ThisUser(context: context)
var data = [String: String]()
for child in children {
    data[child.key] = child.value as? String
}
data["uid"] = currentUser!.uid
```

The `child.key` string matches the attribute in CoreData and I want to put `child.value as? String` in as the value for each CoreData attribute.

Is there a way I can do this without having to create a line of code for each attribute ... ex) `thisUser.uid = data["uid]`

Here is my data model:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this via Core Data introspection. You'd do something like:

- Get the `NSEntityDescription` as `thisUser.entity`.
- Get a list of the properties in the entity, by calling `attributesByName` on the entity description to get a dictionary of `[String: NSAttributeDescription]`.
- The keys for that dictionary are the names of your Core Data properties. Get values from your dictionary with that key. Assign values to your managed object with key-value coding, i.e. `setValue(_:, forKey:)`.
- If necessary you can also use the results of `attributesByName` to find out the type of the property. Use the `attributeType` property of `NSAttributeDescription`.

Basically, find out what attributes your Core Data object has, get their names, and then run through those names to copy data from one place to another.